# BackButton Blackberry issue in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, blackberry

I'm developing a Cordova/Phonegap application for Android, iOS, Blackberry OS and Blackberry10.

My App works fine in Android and iOS. But in blackberries, when "backbutton" is pressed the app aborts :(

In BBOS <= 7 is this useful for my problem?

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", history.back(), false);
```

Edit:

I have added the following in my index.html

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", alert("Heeey, can you read me? :p"), false);
```

And in my simulator of BB 9930 doesn't fire that event, I never saw "Heeey, can you read me? :p" when Backbutton is pressed.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: What version of Cordova are you running with?

Comment: For BBOS (<=7) I'm using Cordova 2.9.0
Can I use newer version for that platform?